# SSH to KVM VM via Host

Tags: networking, kvm

Got couple VMS that I would like to SSH into, got the services running on both using port 2222. Machines have a static IP assigned to them and i got the script from https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking setup, somehow i still cannot ssh into the machines.

Script setup

```
GUEST_IP=192.168.122.100
GUEST_PORT=2222
HOST_PORT=22
```

IPs

```
virsh net-dhcp-leases default
Expiry Time           MAC address         Protocol   IP address           Hostname          Client ID or DUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-26 14:09:10   52:54:00:76:a1:23   ipv4       192.168.122.100/24   blackarch         01:52:54:00:76:a1:23
2020-03-26 13:49:23   52:54:00:aa:19:66   ipv4       192.168.122.130/24   DESKTOP-HHKHGLH   01:52:54:00:aa:19:66
```

IPTables

```
FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.122.100      tcp dpt:EtherNet-IP-1

NAT
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 to:192.168.122.100:2222
```

SSH

```
ssh root@192.168.122.100 -p 2222 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.122.100 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.122.100 [192.168.122.100] port 2222.
```

Any ideas?
Did a tcpdump on guest and i can see some packets but i can't make the connection

Answer (score 0):

Since i could see the packets come in looked into the guest iptables to see what was going on, turns out it was dropping all traffic. Added a simple rule to it and now i can ssh, hopefully this helps someone else.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Just an additional note: if the OS includes an additional security system like SELinux or AppArmor, you might also have to adjust its settings when putting a standard service to a non-standard port (e.g. making `sshd` listen in any port other than 22).